# How do you get Angular bootstrap tooltip to work?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following the tooltip example in the Angular bootstrap [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) but I can't seem to get the tooltip to work. I'm using Angular version 1.5.5 and angular-bootstrap version 0.11.2.

Here is my code:
app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('TooltipDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
//doesn't matter from what I can tell
})
```

index.html

```
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
   <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

</body>
```

tooltip.html

```
<div ng-controller="TooltipDemoCtrl">
```

`<div class="w-col w-col-4 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4 w-clearfix icon-col">`

```
<img width="17" src="../assets/images/pc-icon-two.png" 
uib-tooltip="NOT WORKING" class="info-icon-five1">
</div>
</div>
```

I have an image that I want to use as a tooltip. I tried moving the uib-tooltip in both the img tag and the div tag. Neither works.  What is going on here?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: @ochi no errors in the console. If it is as simple as using uib-tooltip then what is the problem? Is there something that could knock out that directive or is there something to include in the controller that I may have missed?

Comment: You included all the scripts to use ui bootstrap?

Comment: @sebenalern maybe I didn't but I'm not sure what you mean. How do I check? is nganimate required to make this work?

Comment: `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
` and `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>` Should be included in your html file.

Comment: I have       <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script> is that good enough?

Comment: I copied and pasted the link and script into my index.html and I now get the following errors in my console.

Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkz‌​s7'). The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.

AND

GET http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.4/ui-bootstrap-tp%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bls.js

Comment: Did you ever fix your problem?

Comment: @sebenalem I did not. A few other work things came up so I am beginning work on it again right now. I'll check the answers offered first and if none of them work for me I'll post the answer I find.  Thanks for helping sebenalem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="SO.js"></script>


</head>
<body >
   <div ng-controller="TooltipDemoCtrl">
      <div class="w-col w-col-4 w-col-small-4 w-col-tiny-4 w-clearfix icon-col">
      <img width="17" src="SO/nick_pic2.jpg" uib-tooltip="WORKING" class="info-icon-five1">
       </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Angular code:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('TooltipDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

This shows a picture in the upper left corner of the page.

Comment: Given the set up of my index.html, I'm not sure your answer is directly translatable. I'm trying it but I have not gotten it to work. I updated my question with my index.html to try and get on the same playing field.

Comment: I can post more code if you can be specific of what might be relevant. Otherwise, there are many thousands of lines of Angular code so it would be impractical to post it all in this question.

Comment: @sebenalem, what is SO.js referring to? Otherwise I have the exact code pattern and it is not working. Pretty disapointing. I've spent hours on this already. Something so basic so clearly not working. Probably a small idiosyncracy I'm not picking up on. To be clear, you say "This shows a picture in the upper left corner of the page." When you scroll on the picture "WORKING" appears in the tooltip.  That is the functionality that I'm expecting.

Comment: SO.js is just my javascript file name. I think yours is app.js. I can't remember exactly off the top of my head but when I get home I will see what it looks like. In the meantime you should post a picture of what yours looks like.

Comment: @sebenalem what I think may be an issue is that this tooltip is inside a modal. Do you think that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Possibly I am not sure. Try creating a sample program with just the tooltip and try to get that working.

Comment: I tried it outside the modal and still nothing pops up. So much for that theory. How can I check to see if it is even firing?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111261/how-do-you-get-angular-bootstrap-tooltip-to-work