# How to use Bootstrap tooltips with Bootstrap *CDN* in Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

I have included `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` in `index.html` of my Angular project. I want to use Bootstrap tooltips but can't find a way to do so. How do I achieve it without having to do

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Element to add tooltip to:

```html
<p data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Back to Previous Page"></p>
```

Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- meta, title, etc -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does this solve your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904986/how-do-you-get-angular-bootstrap-tooltip-to-work

Comment: @AlexYu Do i need to include angular ui bootstrap tpls.js just to get the tooltip working?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install below packages in angular app.

```js
npm install bootstrap jquery --save
```

Once these packages are installed you need to make below configuration in **angular.json** file. Prefer this way of importing external libraries instead of adding in index.html.

```js
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/spinnerapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

Include **jquery.js** and **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** in the scripts array. Please note **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** by default contains **popper.js**. So no need to include it separately.

Now you can use jquery to call tooltip function from bootstrap as shown below. Please note how to include jquery in **app.component.ts**.

```js
declare var $: any;
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './services/spinner.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'spinnerapp';
 
  showSpinner = false;

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
    Tooltip on top
  </button>
```

**Refer complete example below.**

[Tooltip Bootstrap Code](https://github.com/kodecrash/spinnerapp)

Comment: This does work but it does not answers my question perfectly. I want tooltips to work while using `bootstrap CDN` and *not* install bootstrap through npm

Answer (score 0):

From the Bootstrap official documentation:

> Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning.

> **You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use
> bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js
> in order for tooltips to work!**

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Comment: I already have included ` bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Comment: Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning. You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!